# Class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient in CXF 3.0.7

Tags: java, cxf

I am having trouble in figuring out which jar does WebClient class belongs.
In CXF 2.7 it was in cxf-bundle.jar, but in 3.0.7 I am unable to find it. I've been looking up jars for 2 hours but couldn't get anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean: `org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-rs-client/3.0.7/cxf-rt-rs-client-3.0.7.jar`?

Comment: Thanks! I did not know it was here..

Comment: @Ben Is there any way to know which jar has a particular package or class rather than manually browsing jars. Even on cxf site information about this is not mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post my comment as answer:

Please take a look at:

> org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-rs-client/3.0.7/**cxf-rt-rs-client-3.0.7.jar**

I found this JAR by searching http://mvnrepository.com/ for WebClient-Artifact ID (which i found in the API-Docs for CXF):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

To find JAR's for specific packages, in most cases google is your friend:

Just google for (for example) `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet`

But you can also search/analyze your local JAR's for this String (most ZIP-Tools support searching inside of ZIP/JAR-Files).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error package org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client does not exist,

Added dependecy

org.apache.cxf cxf-rt-rs-client 3.0.0-milestone1

issue resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).